# Google analytics no longer showing conversion

Tags: google-analytics

Google analytics is not longer showing my conversation rates for all my sources except for direct. Anyone know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you provide some of the code where you have your google analytics problem?

Comment: Is it a problem for Goals or eCommerce transactions, or both?